# Create dynamic content with angular

Tags: angular

I would like to build a personal website to upload some of my stuff for friends and family. My working website is www.vezh.me .

I would like to add some functionalities in future, such as - a hidden admin login restricted to my firebase account to edit data.

I would like to create a hidden feature for me as admin where I can can click a button to add new content dynamic by using a custom service with firebase to list the content on my page.

If you check my page, on the home path you can see the content boxes I'm talking about. I'm not sure what I should look for to learn about it.
I want to create those dynamically by clicking a button to open a modal, type a title, description and a image and submit it to firebase and show it instantly on my page like the example listed on my page.

Could you guys help me out and lead me to the right section where I can learn about this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look up Angular Tutorials on Youtube such as Angular Firebase. they are very informative and maybe you stumble across on what your looking for.